# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' (file opening)

Tags: string, byte, python-3.6

I've been unsuccessful with adding a "b" for byte-reading infront of all the strings, even though it should solve the problem according to lots of older threads.
Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__author__ = 'chrispaulson'
import numpy as np
import math as m
import os
import pickle
import pyKriging


class samplingplan():


    def optimallhc(self,n,population=30, iterations=30, generation=False):

            if not generation:
                # Check for existing LHC sampling plans
                if os.path.isfile(b'{0}lhc_{1}_{2}.pkl'.format(self.path,self.k, n)):
                    # codecs.open(filename,'r',encoding='utf8')
                    X = pickle.load(open(b'{0}lhc_{1}_{2}.pkl'.format(self.path,self.k, n), 'rb'))
                    return X
                else:
                    print(self.path)
                    print('SP not found on disk, generating it now.')
```

When referring to the function "optimallhc" with class "samplingplan()" within the main code

```
import pyKriging
from pyKriging.krige import kriging  
from pyKriging.samplingplan import samplingplan

# The Kriging model starts by defining a sampling plan, we use an optimal Latin Hypercube here
sp = samplingplan(2)  
X = sp.optimallhc(20)
```

it returns the following traceback message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-e9ff50d9f93a>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Andreas Luckert/Kriging-plot-Ehingen.py', wdir='C:/Andreas Luckert')

  File "C:\Users\Müller\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Müller\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Andreas Luckert/Kriging-plot-Ehingen.py", line 14, in <module>
    X = sp.optimallhc(20)

  File "C:\Users\Müller\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyKriging\samplingplan.py", line 72, in optimallhc
    if os.path.isfile(b'{0}lhc_{1}_{2}.pkl'.format(self.path,self.k, n)):

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'format'
```

As visible above, I already added the "b" for bytes-handling everywhere, even in other combinations, but it never worked.
I would appreciate it very much, if somebody knew what to do about it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Include the whole traceback please. :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've just edited my question including the entire traceback of the error message.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a file name string using `b'{0}lhc_{1}_{2}.pkl'.format(self.path,self.k, n)` so you can check for its existance using `os.path.isfile`, and this is causing an error because you can't use `.format` on a bytes object?  Try keeping it a string?